# MainMenu disappears when adding ContextMenu every time

Tags: c#

I have had this issue in Visual Studio ever since i started using it years ago, i cannot figure out what is going on, i add a `MainMenu` strip and fill it up with options, i then add a `ContextMenu` (if i need one in the particular application) when i do this, when i debug / build the `MainMenu` strip is gone, but the `ContextMenu` always shows.

I don't have any code as such but i have images to show how it looks in the designer:

Image 1 (When i click on the `MainMenu` control it shows in the designer)

[image]
Image 2 (When i click off the `MainMenu` control it disappears the same on debug / build)

[image]

I have looked over all the code i don't know what else to look at, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: MainMenu was replaced 14 years ago by MenuStrip, recommended to get ahead when you can't show us a repro.

Comment: Ahh i see, so ```MainMenu``` is the older one? i'll just replace it, this will explain why, thank you Hans.